# Have Rhino preload script?

Tags: javascript, rhino

I am currently developing some JavaScript software and often have to load it up in Rhino.  Is there a way I can create a bash script or something to have Rhino load up my software when it launches?

Currently, I have to type `load("path/to/file.js")` every time I want to test something interactively, and I'd rather not.

Comment: I also have the same question for batch script for Windows.

Comment: @OnesimusUnbound Can't you just run a new cmd prompt at the end of your batch script?

Comment: like load("js files");  command("cmd");? I don't think I'll be able access the js enviroment when I'm in the dos prompt. I think creating a java console wrapping around the rhino library and loading the scripts passed in the said java console is the viable solution., though this is too much hassle :(.

Answer (score 1):

If you use the `jrunscript.exe` from your JDK you should be able to specify the files to evaluate before the interactive mode starts, like so:

```
jrunscript -f /path/to/file1.js -f /another/file2.js -f -
```

Now the interactive mode should start in the context of a loaded `file1.js` and `file2.js`.